# I need to set the path for saving the pictures with an application for Android and IOS with UNITY

Tags: android, path, screenshot, unity-game-engine, image

My actual code:

```
function Update() { 
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
       Debug.Log("foto");
       Application.CaptureScreenshot(Application.dataPath + "Screenshot.png");
    }
}
```

I need the path for the output of every photo for this function.

Thanks!

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save files to [Application.persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). Unity apps do not have write permissions to `Application.dataPath` on Android or iOS devices.

Also, don't forget to join the path and the folder name with a forward slash:

```
Application.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshot.png");
```

Comment: i tried your code. But its not saving to Application.persistentDataPath in android. why it happens so ?

Answer (score 0):

`Application.persistentDataPath` of unity always points towards documents folder in `IOS` and to `/mnt/android/data/application-bundle-identifier/` for `android`. 
And if you don't give the path for `Application.CaptureScreenshot` put instead give only the name for the screenshot it'll automatically get saved in the Documents folder of `IOS` haven't tested for `android`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
static function CaptureScreen(){
var filename;
var name :String = GuiScript.stringToEdit;
var allowedScreenshots:int=1000;
for(var i = 0; i <= allowedScreenshots; i++)
    {

        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android){
            filename = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.xxxx.Test01/files/" + name + i + ".png";
        } else {            
            filename =  name + i + ".png";
        }
        if(!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Application.CaptureScreenshot(name + i + ".png" );
            print("ScreenDUMP made!");
            print(i);
            print(name);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            print("filename already exists");
            print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least [3 ways](http://ralphbarbagallo.com/2012/04/09/3-ways-to-capture-a-screenshot-in-unity3d/) for saving some kind of screenshot with Unity3D: [**`Application.CaptureScreenshot`**](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html), [**`Texture2D.ReadPixels`**](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) and [**`RenderTexture`**](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html).

I only know about the first one: `Application.CaptureScreenshot`. It is for sure the simplest one. It doesn't take paths and it will save to `Application.persistentDataPath` or `Application.dataPath + "/../"`, depending on your platform. Unfortunately there's currently no way of knowing for sure or through code only - it's just broken in that way. Also, it is slow and it may take some seconds to process. It runs as a separate process so you should have an Update or a Coroutine waiting for the file to be created before using it for anything.

If you want to choose where the file will be saved with it, you need to do something like this:

```
bool creatingFile = false;
string fileName = "Screenshot.png"
function Update() { 
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Application.CaptureScreenshot(fileName);
        creatingFile = true;
    }
    if (creatingFile) {
        string origin = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
        string destination = "/sdcard/ScreenCapture/" + fileName; // could be anything
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(origin)) {
            System.IO.File.Move(origin, destination);
            creatingFile = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you want to save it so it will show on the gallery, then you'll have a lot more trouble to do it. It's no simple task: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/204372/saving-screenshots-to-android-gallery.html